# Copy file from remote dir to remote sub directory using Paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

How to copy a file in a remote server `/maindir/fil1.txt` to a sub directory `/maindir/subdir/file1.txt`. I have the SFTP implemented using `paramiko`. But it always check for the local path to copy from .

```
filename_full_path='/maindir/fil1.txt'
destfilename_full_path='/maindir/subdir/file1.txt'
sftp.put(filename_full_path, destfilename_full_path)
```

How to tell SFTP that the local path is also in remote host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in the below way

```
   a=paramiko.SSHClient()
   a.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
   a.connect('ip',username='user',password='passw')
   stdin, stdout, stderr = a.exec_command("cp /sourc/file /target/file")
```

Answer (score 5):

A core SFTP protocol does not support copying remote files.
There's draft of [`copy-data`/`copy-file` extension to the SFTP protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00).

But in the most widespread OpenSSH SFTP server the `copy-data` is supported by very recent [version 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0) only. Another servers that do support the extensions are [ProFTPD `mod_sftp`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html) and Bitvise SFTP server.

So even if Paramiko did support it (it does not), it would probably not be of any use to you.

---

Alternatives:

- Download the folder and reupload it to a new location (a pure SFTP solution)
- Use `cp` command in a "exec" channel (not SFTP anymore, requires a shell access) – use [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command).
- Many mistake *copy* and *move*. Moving a file to another folder is supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy or move files as we normally do in an operating system.
You need to follow this to make a file transfer.

```
import paramiko
ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=’hostname’,username=’something’,password=’something_unique’)

ftp_client=ssh_client.open_sftp()
ftp_client.put(‘localfilepath’,remotefilepath’)   #for Uploading file from local to remote machine
#ftp_client.get(‘remotefileth’,’localfilepath’)   for Downloading a file from remote machine

ftp_client.close()
```